# Multiline graph in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, recharts

I’m basically trying to make a simple graph with [Recharts](https://github.com/recharts/recharts) in React.

The problem that I’m having is that I can’t make multiline that the X axis is different for both datasets.

For example: set1:[{x:1.1,y:2.1},{x:1.2,y:2.2}] and set2 :[{x:1.3,y:3.2},{x:1.4,y:3.4}]. I’m not sure why every time I try to make a multiline graph with Recharts, the X axis is always same, and I have lines with different Y axis, but the only X axis.

I tried creating different X and Y tags, but it didn’t help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple XAxis components in your LineChart component, and assign each one a different xAxisId.

```
<LineChart data="{data}">
  <XAxis xAxisId="0" dataKey="x1" />
  <XAxis xAxisId="1" dataKey="x2" />
  <YAxis />
  <Line dataKey="y1" xAxisId="0" />
  <Line dataKey="y2" xAxisId="1" />
</LineChart>


// Data
const data = [
  { x1: 1.1, y1: 2.1, x2: 1.3, y2: 3.2 },
  { x1: 1.2, y1: 2.2, x2: 1.4, y2: 3.4 },
];
```